# Reduce the amount of memory used by an OpenGL texture

Tags: opengl

I want to know how I can reduce the consumption of graphics memory when using textures in OpenGL. My code:

```
  glGenTextures(1,&textura);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB,textura);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB,0,GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ARB,ilancho,ilalto,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,ildata);

  //MAIN LOOP

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB,textura);

  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(320.0,240.0,0.0);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
   glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
   glVertex2f(-320.0, 240.0);
   glTexCoord2d(0.0,480.0);
   glVertex2f(-320.0,-240.0);
   glTexCoord2d(640.0,480.0);
   glVertex2f( 320.0,-240.0);
   glTexCoord2d(640.0,0.0);
   glVertex2f( 320.0, 240.0);
  glEnd();

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB,0);
  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
```

I used RivaTuner to check the consumption of graphics memory and seems to be the same, with or without compression.

What am I doing wrong?

I have an NVIDIA graphics card geforce 6200 512mb ddr2.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [glTexImage2D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) suggest that in the event the compressed format is *not* available, it will *transparently* fallback on the *non-compressed* equivalent internal format. So there are a few conclusions to draw: 1. Your opengl implementation does not support compressed formats and you are experiencing the documented behavior. 2. Your profiling tools of choice gives you inaccurate statistics.

You should be able to query using [internalformat_query](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/internalformat_query.txt) if your implementation has support for a specific internal format. If it doesn't you simply have to use a different compression method, like dxt/s3ct formats.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there any other alternative to reduce the memory consumption of the graphics card?

Comment: @JavierRamírez: For one thing, the DXT (S3TC) texture compression algorithms have (had) issues with non-power-of-two-textures many years ago. If you are using texture rectangles, it leads me to believe that your hardware/software implementation is pre-GL 2.0 and may fall into the category of not liking compressed NPOT textures. If you are only using texture rectangles for non-normalized texture coordinates, you might want to try using a regular 2D texture and calculating the normalized texture coordinates yourself. See if that changes anything.

Comment: I changed textures that are power of two and still not working, any ideas?

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce6_techspecs.html - from the technical specification:  'GeForce 6200 models do not include compression technology.' Like i already suggested you should try a different compression method (dxt/s3tc is not the same as  GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ARB).